# How can I pass the twitter OAuth PIN to my server from iphone?

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone

Here is I want ...

I have an application and i want my updates to be posted on my twitter account ... for that my application has twitter integration ... now i entered my credentials in return it will give us a consumer key and consumer secret key ....then after getting that twitter will give me a OAuth pin .... The problem here is ... I need to send that "OAuth Pin " to server ... How can i send that pin to my server ...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will help you

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Answer (score 0):

You just change your Application type to Browser type in your Twitter developer profile, this problem will be solved.

Comment: By changing that in the twitter developer profile how can i send the pin to my server ....

Comment: If you change that to browser application, you only need to send consumerkey,consumersecret and callbackurl, i think you already go through this steps..